# Host with identical ips and subnet mask different

Tags: networking, networkmanager, network-interface, network-protocols

Two host with following IP’s. How they will communicate.?
With and without a router.

Case a. 1.1.1.1/24 & 1.1.1.2/24

Case b. 1.1.1.1/24 & 1.1.1.2/32

In case a, they will communicate via switch locally but what happens in case b, will they be able to communicate each other??

Can any explain the what happens in case b?

Answer (score 0):

A router makes no difference in the first case as the IPs are on the same subnet.

it is unclear that the hosts would be able to connect in the second case - I would expect traffic from the first machine would reaach the second one directly but the return path is undefined. It is unclear from your description how this router gateway would be reached - and the traffic, in the naive case would not go anywhere or would go through the default gateway. (Im not saying its not possible, just that thr answer is not defined based  on the information provided).

It is alao possible that static arp is being used in which case I *think* the machines may be able to communicate directly even in the absence if a router.

Comment: Static ARP wouldn't be of much use (the sender either would be able to make a dynamic ARP query/response anyway, or wouldn't even get to the point of trying to make an ARP lookup of any sort). Static IP routes could be used, however.